# Capturing (almost) free piece by King

Tags: rules, pins, king-safety

Here's a position in a chess puzzle:

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "5rk1/p7/Q1n3pp/3q1p1n/2B2P2/4P2P/P5rK/R4R2 w - - 0 1"]
```

The rook had captured a pawn, resulting in a check. The rook is supported by the Queen, but the Queen itself is pinned by the bishop and hence will not be able to protect the rook if the King takes it.

Shouldn't King-captures-Rook be a valid move in this case?

Comment: @DM It is only partially related. Yes, in both cases, a pinned piece can check the opponent, but in this example, he has the opportunity to take a piece on g2, and the real question is does the pinned Qd5 still influence g2, and it does. That other question does not address that at all.

Comment: No  -  The K can NOT take the R legally

Comment: Not the same question...reopen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, absolutely not. You are putting your king in check first from the Qd5.

If you think about this way: Who could take the other king first since that really is what checkmate is? In this case, Kxg2 Qxg2 captured the white king first, and only after would Bxg8 take the black king...White lost the king first.

Your thought also does not hold up to logic: White makes an illegal move, so black cannot?

Comment: I see, that settles it. Thanks!

Comment: It is also simply the laws of chess. I was just trying to give you the logic behind it.

Comment: So it was my ignorance. Sorry, I should've read the rulebook first

Comment: You may be in the U.S., and thus, use USCF rules, but for this purpose, the laws of chess are the same. Read article 3.9.2 here: https://old.fide.com/fide/handbook.html?id=207&view=article And no problem...there is a lot to learn.